# Using the power rule to find the derivative of $\frac{d}{dx} (\sqrt x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Using the power rule, $\frac{d}{dx} (x^n) = n x^{n-1}$, where $n = \frac{1}{2}$ to find the derivative of:

$$
\frac{d}{dx} (\sqrt x)
$$

Steps:

(1) $= \frac{d}{dx}(x^{1/2})$

(2) $= \frac{x^{-1/2}}{2}$

(3) $= \frac{1} {2\sqrt x}$

I get confused at the last two steps. How does the numerator become $x^{-1/2}$ and the denominator become ${2}$ in step 2? And then the numerator $1$ in step 3?

Comment: What are your own steps ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d(\sqrt x)}{dx}=\frac{d(x^{1/2})}{dx}=\frac12x^{1/2-1}=\frac12x^{-1/2}=\frac{x^{-1/2}}2=\frac12\frac1{x^{1/2}}=\frac1{2x^{1/2}}=\frac12\frac1{\sqrt x}=\frac1{2\sqrt x}.$$